# Cannot sent pdf file via POST API using JSON Format

Tags: json

This is my json to send post request at one time.
[enter image description here]
It need me to send 3 parameter and 1 one of it is pdf file which must be String and encoded in Base64 string.
The file I have uploaded in postman>file location,

But after send the post request , I got this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYZ1q.png)

I tried to sent Request using Postman in JSON format with the value is in String including the pdf file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSF83.png)

Answer (score 0):

Such files you can send via form-data if your API supports it.

You can add multiple keys with type `text` or `file`. email and the name can by type `text` and the pdf file should be the type `file`. For the file uploads, you can send additional info and usually we send the file name as the key.

[image]

After adding the form data, postman request and curl would be like as follows.

[image]

Comment: I used this way but got error. It seems the API cannot use this way. Any other suggestions ?
"error": "Input validation error",
    "validation": [
        {
            "instancePath": "",
            "schemaPath": "#/required",
            "keyword": "required",
            "params": {
                "missingProperty": "email"
            },
            "message": "must have required property 'email'"

Comment: Here the problems seems to be missing email. Have you added email as another form data?

Comment: yes I have provide it.

Comment: I have added another screenshot and can you check whether you have set it as the same?

Comment: yes, same as it. I have add the ss image it in the question